# When should I increment the sequence number vs creating a brand new Tx?

Tags: transactions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is TxIn’s sequence?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2025/what-is-txins-sequence)

What are the logical conditions that would require me to change a sequence number?

Suppose there is this transaction

```
  txid: abcdefghi...  sequence:1  input:1someVanityName  output:1otherVanityName  ...
```

... and the people who mutually created this TX decide to revise some information.   Perhaps change the amount, or lock duration.  [Since a tx number will change once the sequence # changes,](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/5888/1878) (or any change for that matter) when should I logically change the sequence number?

- ...when I change the amount or lock duration?
- ...when I change the output script?
- ...when I add / remove addresses from the input portion of the tx?
- ...when I add / remove addresses from the output portion of the tx?

Eventually I may modify the transaction in such a way it has no resemblance to the original tx... and may apply to a whole different set of circumstances.

When should I increment the sequence number versus creating a new tx?

Comment: Set it to UINT_MAX (e.g., FFFF). TXIN isn't used currently: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/2032/153